# Making a alert box when a certain score is reached in .js

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am trying to make a Rock-Paper-Scissor game with decreasing score.

When score '0' is reached my script should display an alert box. Saying either `you lose` or `you win`

How do I do that in JavaScript?

I also don't want the code to display negative values further.

```
var cpu_score = 5;
var me_score = 5;

function stone() {
  var choice = ["stone", "paper", "scissor"];
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var cpu_choice = choice[num];

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "CPU choosed: " + cpu_choice;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "YOU choosed: stone";

  if (cpu_choice == "paper") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "YOU LOSE! OH PITY GOD!";
    cpu_score--;
  }
  if (cpu_choice == "stone") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "Close LUCK! It's DRAW!";
  }
  if (cpu_choice == "scissor") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "WON THE A.I! GREAT";
    me_score--;
  }

  document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = cpu_score;
  document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = me_score;
}


function paper() {
  var choice = ["stone", "paper", "scissor"];
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var cpu_choice = choice[num];

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "CPU choosed: " + cpu_choice;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "YOU choosed: paper";

  if (cpu_choice == "scissor") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "YOU LOSE! OH PITY GOD!";
    cpu_score--;
  }
  if (cpu_choice == "paper") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "Close LUCK! It's DRAW!";
  }
  if (cpu_choice == "stone") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "WON THE A.I! GREAT";
    me_score--;
  }

  document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = cpu_score;
  document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = me_score;
}



function scissor() {
  var choice = ["stone", "paper", "scissor"];
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var cpu_choice = choice[num];

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "CPU choosed: " + cpu_choice;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "YOU choosed: scissor";

  if (cpu_choice == "stone") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "YOU LOSE! OH PITY GOD!";
    cpu_score--;
  }
  if (cpu_choice == "scissor") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "Close LUCK! It's DRAW!";
  }
  if (cpu_choice == "paper") {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "WON THE A.I! GREAT";
    me_score--;
  }

  document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = cpu_score;
  document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = me_score;
}
```

Comment: Unsolicited code review comment:  You can/should do this with just one function.  Each of your functions essentially does the same thing.  Use parameters in your functions to DRY it iup.

Comment: What is currently not working? Where is your `alert()` and is there any errors displayed? - Yeah, definitely have a single method that takes in the player choice and cpu choice and evaluates them. This is spaghetti at it's tastiest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `your choice` to the function and proceed with testing based on that argument, without the need of three distinct functions that are basically the same.

```
var cpu_score = 5;
var me_score = 5;

function round(myChoice) {
  var choice = ["stone", "paper", "scissor"];
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  var cpu_choice = choice[num];

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "CPU choosed: " + cpu_choice;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "YOU choosed: " + myChoice;

  if (cpu_choice === myChoice) {
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "Close LUCK! It's DRAW!";
  } else if (cpu_choice === 'stone') {
    if (myChoice === 'paper') {
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "YOU LOSE! OH PITY GOD!";
      cpu_score--;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "WON THE A.I! GREAT";
      me_score--;
    }
  } else if (cpu_choice === 'paper') {
    if (myChoice === 'scissor') {
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "YOU LOSE! OH PITY GOD!";
      cpu_score--;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "WON THE A.I! GREAT";
      me_score--;
    }
  } else if (cpu_choice === 'scissor'){
    if (myChoice === 'stone') {
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "YOU LOSE! OH PITY GOD!";
      cpu_score--;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "WON THE A.I! GREAT";
      me_score--;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML = cpu_score;
  document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML = me_score;

  if (cpu_score === 0) {
    alert('You Win');
  }
  if (me_score === 0) {
    alert('You Lose');
  }
}
```

And finally show the message if anyone's score reaches 0.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time! I came across switch and case, which are even more easier.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
if(me_score <= 0){alert("put here the text you want in the alert box")}
```

that should give you the alert box when you score reaches 0 or below.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a couple of simple `if` statements and the `alert()` function:

```
if (cpu_score <= 0) {
    alert('you win')
}
if (me_score <= 0) {
    alert('you lose')
}
```

This logic could be placed in a function named `checkGameOver()` and it could be called every time a round is complete.